# Webpack2. Настройка postcss-loader в совокупности с sass-loader

Tags: webpack2

```
{
test: /\.scss$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                        },
                        'postcss-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        },
                    ]
                })
}
```

Но префиксы не расставляются. Как правильно настроить автопрефиксер?

содержимое postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
        plugins: [
            require('autoprefixer')
        ]
    };
```

Comment: Конфига у postcss нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy Конфиг етсь, отредактирвооал пост

Comment: А разве эти параметры не должны быть внутри вебпаковского конфига - там, где настраивается лоадер?

Comment: В другом проекте, в котором я не использую sass, все  работало именно так

Comment: Лоадеры в правильном порядке?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      'autoprefixer': {browsers: ['last 2 versions']}
    }
  }


{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { 
                            loader: 'css-loader', 
                            options: { 
                                sourceMap: isDevelop,
                            } 
                        }, 
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                            options: {sourceMap: isDevelop}
                        },
                        { 
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: { sourceMap: isDevelop } 
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
```